# Question: Prounounciation of a date?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am struggling with a pronunciation of a date (birthday). The very end. So if I would like to pronounce "16-oг". Would the following be correct:

"Шестнáдцaть-**eva**".

I am struggling a little with how to transform the -oг into a correct termination and pronunciation. Would appreciate some input. I have struggled with this part during longer period of time.

Comment: Russian transcriptions should be written either with IPA etc., or with cyrillics.  Not with "-eva" or other English words.

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant "16-го" (not "16-ог").

The pronunciation of the last two syllables is

> -тәвә

(both letters '**о**' are without emphasis, but the second of them is even less stressed, more "*lost*", so to speak) and the entire word is something like

> шәсн**А**<sub>т</sub>цәтәвә

Note that the first '**т**' is omitted in the pronunciation and the '**д**' before '**ц**' becomes non-vocal, '**т**', which BTW, almost disappears  (sorry, I'm not good at writing in IPA).

Because the ending of the word in genitive case loses its soft sign, the sound '**т**' is hard (compared to the *cardinal number 16*, for instance).  The nominative case of the ordinal number ("*шестнадцатое*") also has the hard '**т**' in the postfix.